# PHP - How to specify multiple Bing Map pushpins in POST to URL

Tags: php

The following html works just fine:

```
<form action="https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Map/Road/? 
key=MY_API_KEY" method="Post">
<input name="pp" value="23.936667,-82.126667;47;CO2CW">
<input name="pp" value="39.470267,-98.107923;47;N0LLH">
<input type=Submit value="Submit">
```

Above Example at: http://www.qsomap.org/bingtest.html

I'm developing a PHP program that needs to POST to that URL containing 1 to 100 "pp" (pushpins) values. I found examples using CURL but the array doesn't have duplicate keys. I need to specify up to 100 "pp" values. How do I do this?

Comment: Take a look at [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701719.aspx#Anchor_0).  FYI, that's the top result for searching "bing pushpin post".

Comment: Yes, I read the docs which is how I know what data to post to BING to get a map. Nothing in the docs is PHP command specific. What PHP commands will accomplish the same thing as the HTML example?

Comment: I finally figured it out. PHP Post application working fine.